# how to execute command before eventhandler

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

an eventhandler for button

```
private async void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

and I have also command for the same button inside the `viewModel`

```
public Command LoginCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {

        });
    }

}
```

the problem is I want to use `validation` on value(consumed from Api) that returned inside the command and the Navigation lies inside the Event Handler so it Navigate before Validation so how execute command before eventhandler

Comment: whats your scenario for validation? if button clicked? also what button?

Comment: I don't see why you would have a command and a clicked event on the same button ? For UI purpose (green button if logged in, red if not) i wouldn't go this way if using Mvvm

Comment: @Valkyriee inside btnClicked event handler there are the Conditions of Validation and the Navigation and in the Command inside VM there where i Return Data from API these data will be checked inside the event handler but what is happened by nature in the debug is it goes to the navigation and condition before implement what is inside the Command

Answer (score 2):

`Command`s have a `CanExecute` method that you can use for validation. You pass in a predicate to the constructor and it execute that if you were to call

```
LoginCommand.CanExecute(this);
```

You can pass in any `object` into that method.

This seems to be the best fit for you.